# Java ¿Cómo puedo saber si tengo acceso a una Base de Datos Sql Server?

Tags: java, base-de-datos

Me gustaría saber cuál sería la forma correcta de comprobar si tengo acceso a una base de datos usando Java. Querría saber con qué método o métodos se podría realizar dicha consulta. 
Actualmente tengo una conexión a un servidor Jboss en el cual tengo los datos de conexión de las bases de datos (de SQL Server) a las que acceso dentro del fichero de configuración standalone.xml y ya me hace la conexión directamente.
Para realizar la comprobación simplemente hago lo siguiente: Crear un método booleano por ejemplo existeConexión. Dentro de ese método hago una llamada a la base de datos y si hay un error lo capturo en un try/catch para que no "rompa" la ejecución. Si hay error existeConexion devuelve falso y así ya lo compruebo pero no es una manera muy "limpia" de hacerlo.
Muchas gracias.

Mi interés en ello consiste en que si no se puede extraer los datos de una base de datos lo haga desde otro lado.

Creando un código rápido de ejemplo quedaría sería algo así:

```
     private ModelAndView crearVistaListado(
        final BuscadorConsultasGeneralesPresupuestoForm 
    buscadorConsultasGeneralesPresupuestoForm,
        final Locale locale, final ModelAndView mav) {


    /* Por aquí iría código innecesario. Para introducir los valores sería algo así*/

    Arrays.asList(TipoVision.values()));
    final boolean existeConexionABBDDPrincipal = 
    dropdownConsultasBaseDeDatosAProvider.comprobacionAcceso();

    if (existeConexionABBDDPrincipal ) {          
        mav.addObject("valoresCombo1" , 
        dropdownConsultasBaseDeDatosAProvider.obtenerDatosCombo();
    }
    else {
        mav.addObject("valoresCombo1" , 
        dropdownConsultasBaseDeDatosBProvider.obtenerDatosCombo();
    }
    return mav;
}
```

Método que uso para la comprobar la conexión en la clase dropdownConsultasBaseDeDatosAProvider

```
public boolean comprobacionAcceso() {
    boolean existeConexionABBDDPrincipal = true;
    try {          
        List<String> consultaCombo1 = 
        consultasBaseDeDatosAService.obtenerDatos();
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        return existeConexionABBDDPrincipal = false;
    }
    return hayConexiónABDXumco;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a a Stackoverflow. Por favor [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/130339/edit) colocando la manera en la que lo estás haciendo y los expertos te dirán si es una forma *limpia* de hacerlo o no, y quizá se te podrán sugerir mejoras. Es importante que cuando plantees una pregunta muestres lo que has hecho hasta el momento.

Comment: Podrías agregar tu código de "comprobación de acceso", podría darte una solución a lo que planteas, pero me gustaría saber como lo haces, ya que podría ser lo mismo. Recuerda [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Gracias por el consejo. Creado un código rápido, que el original no puedo ponerlo y es demasiado largo.

Comment: No estaria entendiendo cual es el problema. si el codigo de comprobacion ya lo tenes, que otra cosa estas buscando?

Comment: gbianchi. 
Querría saber si habría algún método para comprobar si hay conexión a una base de datos sin tener que hacer una consulta, capturar el error para que la aplicación siga funcionando (si no "rompe"), y meterle un booleano que me diga si hubo error o no.
Al hacer esto se me genera una pila de errores en consola y quería evitar eso.